# How can I periodically run a shell command using launch agents on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

We have a Kerberos single-sign-on system in our company. This means that I can just type `kinit user@DOMAIN` in the terminal, and then I can access all IT resources like file servers, internal wiki, svn server etc.

The problem is, I stay logged in for only 10 hours, so I need to run `kinit` every morning when I wake my computer from sleep, and every time I restart the computer.

Is there a way to run this command automatically when I start the computer, and every ten hours after that?

I did some research and I assume the correct way to do this is to use a launch agent, because the command must be run as the current user (kinit needs the password from the keychain).

I tried using the following launch agent file, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.jabakobob.auto-kinit</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>user</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/kinit</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>user@DOMAIN</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10800</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I don't know why this launch agent doesn't work, and I have no clue how to debug it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`/Library/LaunchAgents/` are tied to individual users where as `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` are tied to the machine as a whole. After the system is booted and the kernel is running, property list files found in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` are loaded first as these are system-level daemon.

Try to put your plist in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and see if it works. Because goal is to  run `kinit` at boot up, so should not matter if it is loaded at system-level.

If its not working please reply here with your findings.